# NSTimer with NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nstimer

How do I have an NSTimer with a UIButton that changes its text from Start to Stop, Also another UIButton will be added to pause the timer. So, You press start and then the timer will show in a label in hours, minutes and seconds. While the timer is running, is there a way to pause the timer ( I heard you have to use NSUserDefaults). Also is there a way to save the time at which the start button was pressed and then to save the time that the button was pressed again to stop? Also when the pause button is pressed to pause the timer and when pause is pressed again it will resume the timer?

Comment: This is fairly basic stuff. You really should review the fundamentals; that way you can solve problems like these on your own saving yourself the headache of waiting for others to do so.

Comment: @user3121577 qegal is right, I would like to help but its really easy in Xcode and hard to write in a post.
If you try and don't manage then come back again :)

Comment: So far, I do have a timer and stuff but I do not know how to save the start time and stop time and to pause the timer.

Comment: Ok then, how do I just get to save the start time and stop time?

Answer (score 2):

If you need a timer that doesn't support pausing, you only need to know the `NSDate` at which the timer started so that you can calculate the time elapsed. Create an instance variable:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *timerStartDate;
```

When the button is tapped:

```
- (void)startTimer
{
    self.timerStartDate = [NSDate date];
}
```

Your NSTimer is not to keep track of the time, but to periodically update the label. Create an instance variable:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *labelUpdateTimer;
```

and update the `-startTimer` method:

```
- (void)startTimer
{
    self.timerStartDate = [NSDate date];

    // start timer to update label
    if (!self.labelUpdateTimer) {
        self.labelUpdateTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(updateLabel)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
    }
}

- (void)updateLabel
{
    NSTimeInterval secondsElapsedSinceTimerStart = 0;
    if (self.timerStartDate) {
        secondsElapsedSinceTimerStart = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.timerStartDate];
    }

    NSString *formattedTime = <format time elapsed the way you like>;
    self.label.text = formattedTime;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    // make sure timer is not firing anymore!
    if (_labelUpdateTimer) {
        [_labelUpdateTimer invalidate];
        _labelUpdateTimer = nil;
    }
}
```

However, if you want to be able to pause the timer, besides calculating the time elapsed since the timer last started, you'll need to store the time previously elapsed (if you started/paused the timer before). Create an instance variable:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval previouslyElapsedSeconds;
```

And when you pause the timer:

```
- (void)pauseTimer
{
    // update elapsedSeconds
    if (self.timerStartDate) {
        self.previouslyElapsedSeconds += [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.timerStartDate];
        self.timerStartDate = nil;
    }

    [self.labelUpdateTimer invalidate];
    self.labelUpdateTimer = nil;
}
```

Update `-updateLabel`:

```
- (void)updateLabel
{
    NSTimeInterval secondsElapsedSinceTimerStart = 0;
    if (self.timerStartDate) {
        secondsElapsedSinceTimerStart = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.timerStartDate];
    }

    // account for previously elapsed time
    NSTimeInterval totalSecondsElapsed = self.previouslyElapsedSeconds + secondsElapsedSinceTimerStart;

    NSString *formattedTime = <format time elapsed the way you like>;
    self.label.text = formattedTime;
}
```

NSUserDefaults will be required only if you want to keep timing even if the app is shut down (not just backgrounded). In that case store `previouslyElapsedSeconds` and `timerStartDate` in NSUserDefaults instead of as instance variables.

Comment: Do I still NSUserDeafaults even if the app is running the the Background?

Comment: While backgrounded your instance variables are not released unless the system needs to shut down your app to clear up memory for another process, so no you normally do not need `NSUserDefaults`. However there is a chance that after backgrounding your app will be shut down (by the user or the system). It's your call whether the timing should continue then. If so, then you need to save those values to `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have `NSDate` objects `startTime` and `stopTime`

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:startTime forKey:@"startTime"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:stopTime forKey:@"stopTime"];
```

Or you can use floats `startTimef` and `stopTimef`

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:startTimef forKey:@"startTime"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:stopTimef forKey:@"stopTime"];
```

Check out the [`NSUserDefaults` docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject%3aforKey%3a).

Here's a great [set of tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials).

Comment: Whats the difference between an object and a float? Sorry I am a beginner

Comment: Well, a float is one of the primitive data types. You should start with a tutorial to get some basic programming concepts down.  http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials